'csv' file as input from a pop-up window in python using PyQt5
Trying to select a csv file as input from a pop-up window in python using PyQt5.
self.ip_info_path = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(caption="Select folder containing IP addr 'csv' files")

The error its throwing each time, which leads to crashing of the software itself is:-
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

During debugging, I discovered that the code does not even proceed to line number2 and crashes while the pop-up window is asking option to select an Input File, ie, @ self_url_file_Path
Please help, as to how to resolve this memory access issue?

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

I can't test it because you didn't create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run - but most examples use parent= in getExistingDirectory()

if you don't have longer error message then it will be problem to solve it. It can be wrong argument, or missing some module or C/C++ library, etc.

Run the script from a terminal or prompt, which should show a more comprehensive output. If you still cannot fix it, then [edit] your post and provide a proper [mre], because we cannot guess what's wrong with your code just by reading one line.
